# Laravel 4: How to make pagination

Tags: php, pagination, laravel, laravel-4

Right now i have a working photo-gallery with basic Crud.
In the view Show, under the picture, i would like to add the pagination: giving the possibility to watch other pictures remaining in the Show view, instead of coming back to the Index view.

I try to read the documentation: http://four.laravel.com/docs/pagination
But is not working.

Can someone please tell me what exactly i have to do?

Thank you very much!

EDIT:

This is the Show method:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $photo = Photo::find($id);

    return View::make('photos.show', compact('photo'));
}
```

And this is the Show view:

```
@extends('master')

@section('blog')

<div class="span12 well">
  <div class="span12">
   <h4> {{ $photo->title }} </h4> 

   <p>{{ $photo->caption }} </p>
  </div>  


</div>


<div class="span12 well">
   <figure>
     <img src="../{{ $photo->path }}" alt="{{ $photo->caption }}">
       <br><br>
       <div class="span2">
         {{ link_to_route('photos.index', '&laquo; Back to Index') }}
           </div>
   </figure>
</div>


@stop
```

Comment: Could you share with us what you have so far?  There are various methods mentioned in that documentation...

Comment: Ok, i have edited the question, adding the Show method and the Show view. The pagination i would like to add under the photo in the Show view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your controller

```
public function show(){
    $photos = Photo::paginate(10);
    return View::make('photos.show', array('photos' => $photos));
}
```

and then in your view just do this

```
@foreach ($photos as $photo)
{{ $photo->title }}
@endforeach

// executed from passed variable into view
{{ $photos->links() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your model setup already

In your controller a sample RESTful controller:

```
class PhotosController extends BaseController {
    public function getPhotos() {
       $data['photos'] = Photos::paginate(10);

       return View::make('hello')->with($data);
    }
}
```

** You can always change the value, depends on how many you want to display.

And in your view:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
 <!--YOUR TABLE OR PHOTO's HERE-->
 {{ $photos->links(); }}
</body>
</html>
```